# AWS lex return error Invalid Lambda Response

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-lex

I am using AWS Lex and configured with nodejs lambda when intent will fullfill. But it throw error response of fulfilment of intent i.e,

> Invalid Lambda Response: Received invalid response from Lambda: Can
> not construct instance of IntentResponse, problem: The validated
> object is null at [Source:
> {"sessionAttributes":{},"recentIntentSummaryView":[],"activeContexts":[],"dialogAction":{"type":"Close","fulfillmentState":"Fulfilled","message":{"contentType":"PlainText","content":"Okay
> Added"}}}; line: 1, column: 197]

Comment: The format appears to be correct. Have you tried returning a response without the sessionAttributes, recentIntentSummaryView and activeContexts?